# What is the datatype of &(char *) in C?

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose I have

```
char *t = "XX";
```

I am wondering what is the type of &t. Is it char or array?

Comment: `&t` is definitely `char **`. Did you mean `*t`?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic and array notation are interchangable to some degree in C, which may be part of what's confusing you. That's been discussed previously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `&t` for any expression is a pointer to the type of `t`.  In this case the type of `t` is `char*` hence the the type of `&t` is `char**`

Answer (score 4):

Since `t` is a pointer, `&t` is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: But I thought & accesses the value of the pointer. How can that still be a pointer?

Comment: `&` gives you the address.  A pointer holds the address.  Since you asked for the type of `&t`, that will be a pointer to a pointer, or a place to hold the address of a pointer.

Comment: @Mat.S `&` does not access anything. `*` would dereference (access) the value of the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You *need* to know what a pointer is and who does it works.

```
TYPE * VAR = VALUE;
```

Here you have:

- `TYPE`: the type of data that you are storing
- `*`: means it is a pointer of TYPE
- `VAR`: is the variable that store a pointer of TYPE
- `VALUE`: value of TYPE

And `&VAR` is a pointer to `VAR`. In your case `VAR` is a pointer also, so `&VAR` is a *pointer to a pointer*.